# При отключении Instant Run в Android Studio, падают ошибки при компиляции

Tags: java, android, gradle

Всем привет, есть проблема небольшая, при отключении  Instant Run в Android Studio, падают ошибки при компиляции
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]